# Implement OAuth2 in custom plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, oauth

I'm trying to integrate an OAuth2 server in WordPress using [Wp OAuth CE plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/) but it will install and not activate because give a fatal error.

The error when I try to activate the plugin in my localhost is

```
Undefined variable $res in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-content\plugins\oauth2-provider\includes\functions.php on line 388

Fatal error Uncaught TypeError: openssl_pkey_get_details(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type OpenSSLAsymmetricKey, null given in C:\...
```

At the moment I'm creating a custom plugin that will expose some custom routes and if there isn't any valid plugin alternative to have an OAuth2 server in wordpress, I'm thinking to implement it by using [this library](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) and by providing some dedicated routes to get a token, authorize an user and retrive user informations.

Did anyone implemented OAuth2 in WordPress and how I can achive it in the better way possible?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/410244/edit) to give us more information. What's the fatal error that you're seeing? What's the relevant code look like in your custom plugin?

Comment: @PatJ I've edited the question to add the error that the plugin give to me. I don't know why it occur because I just downloaded and installed the plugin from wordpess plugin directory. I'm on last version of XAMPP with php 8.1